# Changes in DNA and forensic cases

Tags: dna

If DNA changes over time, how is it that forensic DNA gathered decades ago can be matched to a person today for solving crimes?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular it is not clear what you mean by "DNA changes over time" — are you asking about mutations that accumulate in living tissue, or degradation of  specimens? ——— We also encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Thanks! 

Comment: @Dirigible ?? DNA profiling is not based on sequencing at least until 2010, it is doing a fingerprint of the reaction product of a PCR+electrophoresis with specially designed primers targeting [microsatellites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsatellite#Forensic_and_medical_fingerprinting) https://www.yourgenome.org/facts/what-is-a-dna-fingerprint